# how can I set a value of SWIGTYPE like SWIGTYPE_p_LPCSTR using java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

how can I set a value of SWIGTYPE like SWIGTYPE_p_LPCSTR using java?

I have generated java interface class using swig from a c++ header file.

There is a problem that many C++ types were wrapped into class like this:

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_LPCSTR {
    private transient long swigCPtr;

    protected SWIGTYPE_p_LPCSTR(long cPtr, @SuppressWarnings("unused") boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_LPCSTR() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_LPCSTR obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

Actually, I just want it to be a simple type like string or int.I guess this is a pointer, but don't know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

These are opaque classes. You don't really use them, they are just passed around.
Please see the [SWIG 3.0 Documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/index.html)

My guess of what's happening here is that your header has a LPCSTR which is a macro possibly defined in another header (probably as char*) and SWIG doesn't know what the macro expands to so instead of using its typemap for strings it wraps the LPCSTR into this proxy class.